# GRPC Golang dial options how to use the WithMaxMsgSize function

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I'm trying to change the golang dial options changing it's max message size but was not able to find any example on how to use the function WithMaxMsgSize to change receive/send file size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the method, all you have to do is just implement it inside the struct when initializing the server

```
s := grpc.NewServer(grpc.MaxSendMsgSize(1024*1024*50), grpc.MaxRecvMsgSize(1024*1024*50))
```